# Failed to Write to Bigquery - Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, google-bigquery, apache-spark-sql

Hi I have written code to write a dataframe I have created to my BigQuery table that I am running through Dataproc using the spark java big query connector My issue is when I do my write like so:

```
filteredInput.write().format("bigquery")
                .option("temporaryGcsBucket", "temp_bucket")
                .mode(SaveMode.Append)
                .save("tables.table_1");
```

I am getting a vague error like this:

```
Error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to write to BigQuery
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.BigQueryWriteHelper.writeDataFrameToBigQuery(BigQueryWriteHelper.scala:69)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.BigQueryInsertableRelation.insert(BigQueryInsertableRelation.scala:43)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.BigQueryRelationProvider.createRelation(BigQueryRelationProvider.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$execute$1(SparkPlan.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:218)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:215)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:176)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.$anonfun$runCommand$1(DataFrameWriter.scala:989)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:163)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:775)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:989)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:438)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveInternal(DataFrameWriter.scala:415)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:293)
    at com.db.lrc.macs.ecomms.bbgemail.spark.pipeline.BbgEmailSparkPipeline.writeToOutput(BbgEmailSparkPipeline.java:117)
    at com.db.lrc.macs.ecomms.bbgemail.spark.EcommsSparkApplication.triggerPipeline(EcommsSparkApplication.java:37)
    at com.db.lrc.macs.ecomms.bbgemail.spark.EcommsSparkApplication.main(EcommsSparkApplication.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:951)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:203)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1039)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1048)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.cloud.bigquery.connector.common.BigQueryClient.loadDataIntoTable(BigQueryClient.java:532)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.BigQueryWriteHelper.loadDataToBigQuery(BigQueryWriteHelper.scala:87)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.BigQueryWriteHelper.writeDataFrameToBigQuery(BigQueryWriteHelper.scala:66)
    ... 38 more
ERROR: (gcloud.dataproc.jobs.submit.spark) Job [248b593282b6403f9cbfb8c85710bd7a] failed with error:
```

I haven't missed the last part of the error it just doesn't specify.
I am interested in the null pointer exception but the error stack isn't giving me much of an indication of what might be causing it and I'm not sure how I can find out more? Is there a way to view the 38 more lines its omitted there.

My table structure is this:

```
 |-- comm_id: string (nullable = false)
 |-- src_sys_name: string (nullable = false)
 |-- send_time_utc: timestamp (nullable = false)
 |-- participant: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- participant_type: string (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- participant_email: string (nullable = false)
 |-- priority: string (nullable = true)
 |-- insertion_date: timestamp (nullable = false)
 |-- run_date: timestamp (nullable = false)
```

& I am using the connector as a Maven dependency this is my version:

```
  <dependency>
           <groupId>com.google.cloud.spark</groupId>
           <artifactId>spark-bigquery-with-dependencies_2.12</artifactId>
           <version>0.24.2</version>
  </dependency>
```

Has anyone experienced this? Or even have any tips on how I can find out more about whats causing the issue?

Comment: Can you please try with the latest connector - 0.27.1 ?

Comment: Also - It worth opening an issue at https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/spark-bigquery-connector/issues for such cases